# Rumors of performance PHP

Tags: php

Once, I heard in a lecture that use `?>` to close PHP files were causing the performance fall, is this true?

It's funny that many php applications, and frameworks really do not close the files with `?>`. Could be due boilerplate or performance?

The spaces in the code, influences the application performance?

Comment: they faked the moon landing as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely not.  There is no measurable performance difference for opening/closing PHP tags, nor spaces in your code.

A common reason for not closing  a PHP tag is so that a stray blank line at the end of the file doesn't end up being output to the client.  If you have a file that is pure PHP, there is no reason to close the PHP tag.

Comment: I almost feel like if I had a downvote button for comments, this would have been downvoted.  Either an answer or a link to the quote who have sufficed.

Comment: Note that trailing newline directly behind `?>` doesn't get echoed.

Comment: @Pemapmodder It's not worth the risk.  Often when there's one new line, there is more than one or a space or something else.  Also I haven't tested with `\r\n` for folks editing on Windows... does PHP's magic handle that too?

Comment: Yes, it does, I just tested it. I added just note that to remind that fact - although it doesn't affect on this topic, just to make it a bit more precise.